# Transparent layout over Google Maps

Tags: android, google-maps, overlay

I am trying to make a layout which contains a map and, on map tap event, I have to open a form.

Can anyone help me on how can I design this layout?

[image: Click to see demo image]

Comment: A custom DialogFragment will do.

Comment: @FrankN.Stein can u please give me some code or show me that how to achieve this because i am new to android

Comment: I find reading [this page](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/dialogs.html) very interesting.

Comment: @FrankN.Stein do i have to open this dialog as an activity? because i want that data in my main activity

Comment: If it is a Fragment, it is not an Activity. DialogFragments are something in between a normal Dialog and a Fragment, since they can also be used as normal Fragments, inside an Activity, rather than on top of it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here are some points that might help you in implementing this behavior:

- Make use of the canvas layer on top of the Google Map Fragment.
- In the *onDraw()* method of your Canvas add the following line:

  ```
  canvas.drawColor(0x00AAAAAA);
  ```

  This will make your canvas transparent and background View will be visible.
- Start drawing the EditTexts & buttons on the canvas layer in the same way as you do in a regular Activity.
- Refer to this [tutorial](http://www.kellbot.com/2009/06/android-hello-circle/) for additional details related to code.